# Create Form Groups Based on Number of Records

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

I want to create FormGroups/FormArrays inside mat-expansion-panel based on number of records I have in my database.

I have a group table 
id | desc      
1  | Group 1 
2  | Group 2

I have detail table 
id | desc         | group_id 
1  | Detail 1.1   | 1 
2  | Detail 1.2   | 1 
3  | Detail 2.1   | 2

Now, I have this codes and it will loop based on number of records

HTML

```
 <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let group of groups"> <!-- based on group table  -->
   <form [formGroup]="group.formGroup">
     <div formArrayName="group.formArray" > 
       <div *ngFor="let detail of details"> <!-- based on detail table -->
       </div>
     </div>
   </form>
 </mat-expansion-panel>
```

TS

```
 ????????
```

I know how to create form group and form array but doing it based on number of records that is divided by mat-expansion-panel... There's where my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really I don't know what king of formGroup/formArray you want to create. I suppose you want a formArray of formGroup, each formGroup has as formControl "id","desc" and a formArray "detail". So we can get something like

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "desc": "group1",
    "detail": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "desc": "Detail 1.1."
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "desc": "Detail 1.2."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "desc": "group2",
    "detail": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "desc": "Detail 2.1."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

to manage FormArrays of FormGroup, it's usefull create function that return a formGroup, like

```
createGroup(data:any):FormGroup
  {
    data=data || {id:null,desc:null,detail:null}
    return new FormGroup({
      id:new FormControl(data.id),
      desc:new FormControl(data.desc),
      detail:data.detail && data.detail.length?
             new FormArray(data.detail.map(detail=>this.createDetail(detail))):
             new FormArray([])
    })
  }
  createDetail(data:any):FormGroup
  {
    data=data || {id:null,desc:null}
    return new FormGroup({
      id:new FormControl(data.id),
      desc:new FormControl(data.desc),
    })
  }
```

Well if we has some like

```
  group=[{id:1,desc:"group1"},{id:2,desc:"group2"}]
  detail=[{id:1,desc:"Detail 1.1.",group_id:1},
  {id:2,desc:"Detail 1.2.",group_id:1},
  {id:3,desc:"Detail 2.1.",group_id:2}
  ]
```

We can create a formArray in ngOnInit

```
  this.form=new FormArray(this.group.map((x:any)=>{
    return this.createGroup({
      ...x,
      detail:this.detail.filter(d=>d.group_id==x.id)
    })
   }))
```

See how we create a FormArray transform each element of this.group to a FormGroup. we pass to our function as "data" the value of each "group" and a new protertie, "detail" that it's an array, the values of details which groupId are equals to id

Well it's the difficult part. the funny is place all in an accordeon

```
<form *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let grp of form.controls" [formGroup]="grp">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
            <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="id">
    </mat-form-field>
    <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="desc">
    </mat-form-field>
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div formArrayName="detail">
      <div *ngFor="let detail of grp.get('detail').controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput formControlName="id">
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
              <input matInput formControlName="desc">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    </div>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
</form>
```

see that we are using the way `*ngFor="let grp of form.controls" [formGroup]="grp"` to get the group of the formArray. This is the manner to manage a FormArray, put `<form [formGroup]="myFormArray">` and loop over myFormArray.controls

You can see in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2zftst?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.html)

NOTE: I put as editable and part of the form the ids too, when really I think it's not necesary

NOTE2: in a submit, you need create a new table of details mapping the form.value

Comment: You gave me what I need. "Thank You. You the Beth" [Insert Mike Tyson pic]